# Artifact in animation / horizontal lines & double images

Tags: video-quality, animation, codec

I'm using Handbrake, with the H.264 Codec (RF:16). It works pretty well with live action, but it produces odd results whenever I try to back up/encode animations. I've attached a screenshot:

[image]

Anything that's static is fine. But for anything moving (like the money tsunami in the image), I get the double image and horizontal lines. When it's moving, the double image isn't as noticeable, but the horizontal lines *really* stick out badly. Can anyone tell me what's going on, and how to fix it? Are there any codecs made precisely for animations?

(It's *really* bad with old psychodelic-type animation. Think "Yellow Submarine" style animation, with lots of bright, flashing colors.)

Answer (score 1):

This artifact is likely the result of interlacing. And to get rid of it, you can deinterlace it.